# Permutation Square Root

Tags: code-golf, permutations, restricted-complexity

In math, a [permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) ***σ*** of order ***n*** is a bijective function from the integers 1...***n*** to itself. This list:

```
2 1 4 3
```

represents the permutation ***σ*** such that ***σ***(1) = 2, ***σ***(2) = 1, ***σ***(3) = 4, and ***σ***(4) = 3.

A square root of a permutation ***σ*** is a permutation that, when applied to itself, gives ***σ***. For example, `2 1 4 3` has the square root ***τ*** =`3 4 2 1`.

```
k           1 2 3 4
τ(k)        3 4 2 1
τ(τ(k))     2 1 4 3
```

because ***τ***(***τ***(k)) = ***σ***(k) for all 1≤k≤n.

#### Input

A list of ***n***>0 integers, all between 1 and ***n*** inclusive, representing a permutation. The permutation will always have a square root.

You may use a list of 0...***n-1*** instead as long as your input and output are consistent.

#### Output

The permutation's square root, also as an array.

#### Restrictions

Your algorithm must run in polynomial time in ***n***. That means you can't just loop through all ***n***! permutations of order ***n***.

Any builtins are permitted.

#### Test cases:

Note that many inputs have multiple possible outputs.

```
2 1 4 3
3 4 2 1

1
1

3 1 2
2 3 1

8 3 9 1 5 4 10 13 2 12 6 11 7
12 9 2 10 5 7 4 11 3 1 13 8 6

13 7 12 8 10 2 3 11 1 4 5 6 9
9 8 5 2 12 4 11 7 13 6 3 10 1
```

Comment: Would I be correct in saying that for a permutation to have a square root then if it contains n cycles of length m then either n is even or m is odd?

Comment: @Neil Yes. Otherwise the permutation can be represented as odd number of swaps.

Comment: Ah yes that's a much better way of putting it.

Comment: [related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266569/how-to-find-the-root-of-permutation)

Answer (score 5):

## Perl, <s>124</s> 122 bytes

Includes +3 for `-alp`

Run with the 1 based permutation on STDIN:

```
rootperm.pl <<< "8 3 9 1 5 4 10 13 2 12 6 11 7"
```

`rootperm.pl`:

```
map{//;@{$G[-1]^$_|$0{$_}}{0,@G}=(@G=map{($n+=$s{$_=$F[$_-1]}++)?():$_}(0+$',0+$_)x@F)x2,%s=$n=0for@F}@F;$_="@0{1..@F}"
```

Complexity is ***O(n^3)***

Comment: Why is the complexity O(n^3)?

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy Because it's a stupid program :-). It considers each pair of elements (even if already handled, O(n^2)) and zips their cycles together (not even knowing when to stop, O(n)) then checks if that would be a proper cycle for a square root. In the program you can see the 3 nested loops as 2 maps and a for

Comment: Oh. Makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 165 <s>167</s> bytes

An unnamed function.

```
PermutationList[Cycles@Join[Riffle@@@#~(s=Select)~EvenQ@*(l=Length)~SortBy~l~Partition~2,#[[Mod[(#+1)/2Range@#,#,1]&@l@#]]&/@#~s~OddQ@*l]&@@PermutationCycles@#,l@#]&
```

Semi-ungolfed:

```
PermutationList[
    Cycles@Join[
        Riffle@@@Partition[SortBy[Select[#,EvenQ@*Length],Length], 2],
        #[[Mod[(Length@#+1)/2Range@Length@#,Length@#,1]]]& /@ Select[#,OddQ@*Length]
    ]& @@ PermutationCycles @ #,
    Max@#
]&
```

Comment: By what magic does this work?

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy if I've understood the semi-ungolfed code correctly, it splits the permutation into cycles, groups them by length, then for the odd ones it raises them to the power (length+1)/2 while for the even ones it pairs them up and riffles them together. (If the even cycles can't be paired then the partition has no square root.)

Answer (score 0):

## Prolog - 69 chars

```
p([],_,[]). p([H|T],B,[I|U]):-p(T,B,U),nth1(H,B,I). f(X,Y):-p(Y,Y,X).
```

Explanation:

```
permutate([], _, []).                 % An empty permutation is empty
permutate([X|Xs], List, [Y|Ys]) :-    % To permutate List
  permutate(Xs, List, Ys),            % Apply the rest of the permutation
  nth1(X, List, Y).                   % Y is the Xth element of List

root(Permutation, Root) :-            % The root of Permutation
  permutate(Root, Root, Permutation). % Applied to itself, is Permutation
```

Comment: I would imagine this takes exponential time.

Comment: Oh, right. I'll have to fix that.